# Commit all changes from the wal file to the GeoPackage

Tags: qgis, geopackage

So I experienced a peculiarity of GeoPackages today.. I thought the wal file was simply a log of the changes occurring in a GeoPackage but it appears that is not the case.

Here's the workflow: I create an empty GeoPackage, start editing, save changes then send the GeoPackage to a college (without the wal file). The GeoPackage is empty.

If I send the wal file suddenly the points appear. If I export the GeoPackage to new GeoPackage and send that (no wal) it works fine.

Is there a way to commit all these changes in the original GeoPackage or am I doomed to re-export or send three files every time?

Comment: You can read how WAL works from here  https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html. I believe that a QGIS user can force checkpointing only by closing all connections to the GeoPackage. Sending three files is not the right method. Right method is to close all connections and wait until the .wal and .shm files have disappeared.

Comment: I did read over that before posting. Does removing the gpkg from the layers panel close the connection? I've never noticed this functionality with qgis before..

Comment: I don't know but you can test it yourself.

Comment: Update: It's been 17 hours and they still exist. There must be something else going on here.

Comment: 17 milliseconds is more realistic time scale if connections are closed as they should. Have you tried to close QGIS totally?

Answer (score 1):

The edits you make are temporarly written to a `.gpkg-shm` and a `.gpkg-wal` file in the same folder as the original `gpkg` file.

These are standard SQLite temporary files, and allow for example `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` commands to be executed.

In my experience, to force committing (thus merging the edits into an actual `gpkg` file) you can either:

- export the layer to a new file
- remove the layer from the Layer panel
- closing the project in QGIS (`Project`->`Close`)
- exit QGIS